# How to provide access to encrypted files without decryption complete?

Tags: java, file, encryption, cryptography, filesystems

I'm writing a small Java application similar to TrueCrypt, it is a container with encrypted user files.

There is a problem with access to encrypted files. At the moment, I'm using this approach:
 1. When connecting the container completely decrypt all files in a common folder.
 2. Mount folder as a drive.
 3. Watch the events in a folder decrypt files using WatchService.
 4. For example, when adding a new file is encrypted, and it is stored in the container.
 5. After disconnecting the container delete all encrypt files and unmount folder.

I would like to find a solution that would allow to decrypt only the files that the user wants to use, such as providing the user access only to the names of the files, and when the user wants to use to decrypt only one file.

The requirements are: to use only native system file manager, don't write own file manager, a decision should be cross-platform.

At the moment, there is an idea to implement the FTP protocol, or WebDAV and mount it as a network drive.

Is there a simple and elegant solution?

Comment: *"Is there a simple and elegant solution?"* Probably not, or at least outside of the realm of Java.

Comment: a) What you essentially want is an encrypted file system image with random access everywhere. Even without crypto, getting this right is some work, then AES/XTS or something like that on the top ... b) If you never at least heard of other block modes than ECB and CBC, I doubt the current idea is secure.

Comment: With Java implementing a WebDAV server is the most efficient approach. Solution like TrueCrypt require kernel-mode drivers, which are not possible with Java.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to encrypt each file in the container separately.  Encrypt the directory separately as well.  When connected, just decrypt the directory file for the user to see.  Other files are decrypted/encrypted as the user opens and saves them.  Use a similar process for subdirectories if any are present.

This is more complex to run than encrypting the whole container in a single large encrypted file.  It will also impose a delay on individual file access due to en/decryption.